# Javascript not executing if statements sequentially

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, bootbox

I'm trying to write a form validator. I expect that it will check all the if statements and finally give a true or false result. But it is returning always true as soon as it called.

```
function validator() {
    var ret = true;

    fname = document.getElementById('fname').value;
    newp = document.getElementById('newp').value;

    if (fname == null || fname == "") {
        bootbox.alert("Name is empty");
        ret = ret && false;

    }

    if (newp.length > 0) {

        bootbox.confirm("Account will be locked",
            function(result) {
                if (result == true) {
                    ret = ret && true;

                } else {
                    ret = ret && false;

                }
            });
    }

    return ret;

}
```

Comment: Are you sure? Is the code being skipped in the debugger? Sounds more like your code is not entering the `if` blocks because their conditions are evaluating to `false`.

Comment: You need to give us recreations step, or better yet simply [debug the code yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/642/debugging#t=201610281328310876296)

Comment: I think it's more simple to return directly when it enter at condition, like: `if ( !fname ) return false;`

Comment: use === and I would also account for undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bootbox confirmation dialog will not block execution of that outer "validator" function. That outer function will return while the confirmation dialog is still showing.

Using something like the Bootstrap dialog code, you really cannot make a function like that. The callback function you pass to the confirmation dialog *will* be invoked, but not until the user interacts with the dialog.

Comment: Thanks, then I have to go back using good old confirm() dialog which has return value, that might help me crafting logic.

Comment: yes, plain `confirm()` should work